# Integral Operator Contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following question:

[image]

I've found the bound as follows $\lvert T f(x)\rvert \le C\lVert f \rVert(x-a)$ using the fact that K is bounded on the closed square so we have $max \lvert K(x,y) \rvert \le C$ for some positive constant C.

Applying T again to this result yields $\lvert T^2f(x) \rvert \le C^2\lVert f \rVert (x-a)^2$, however I know that the answer is $\lvert T^n f(x) \rvert \le \frac 1{n!}C^2\lVert f\rVert (x-a)^n$.

Any hints on where I am going wrong in obtaining the factorial would be much appreciated.

Comment: looks like when you took the integral of $C||f||(x-a)$, you didn't remember that it is supposed to be $C||f||\frac 12(x-a)^2$. Basically, use the bound and keep integrating it...

Comment: I see that's the result with you integrate with respect to x, however I thought that I need to integrate it with respect to y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $$|Tf(x)| \leq C
\parallel f\parallel (x-a) $$ so that $$
|T(Tf)(x)|=\bigg|\int_a^x K(x,y)\int_a^y K(y,z) f(z)dz
 dy\bigg|\leq \int_a^x |K| \int_a^y |K| |f| dz dy $$ $$\leq
\int_a^x
 C (C\parallel f\parallel )(y-a) dy =C^2
  \parallel f\parallel \frac{(x-a)^2}{2} $$

Continuously we have $$ |T^n f(x)| \leq C^n
  \parallel f\parallel \frac{(x-a)^n}{n!} $$

(2) And note that $\frac{c^n}{n!} \rightarrow 0$ is followed by
considering $e^c = \sum \frac{ c^n}{n!}$.